# How to get the name of the javascript file you are debugging in Firefox's developer tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-developer-tools

While debugging javascript in Firefox's developer tools, I can't seem to find a quick way to see the name of the js file I am debugging.
I know that I can manually scroll in the "Sources" pane until I find the name highlighted, but most of the time there are a lot of files and it is frustrating.
In Chrome dev tools the file name is the name of the tab, but firefox dev tools doesn't have tabs (doh!).
It would be really nice if firefox dev tools implemented tabs to solve this and other issues.

I ask if someone knows a quick way, hotkey, addon, or something to visualize the js file name currently in view.

images describing the issue:

[image: Firefox dev tools doesn't have tabs]

[image: Chrome has tabs with names]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox 56 ships with a new debugger frontend, which has tabs for the individual scripts. So it's much easier to see the name of the script you're currently debugging.

Firefox 56 is [released on the 28th of September 2017](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar).

[image: Script name in tab of new debugger frontend]

Comment: I was waiting until it was actually released to mark the answer as valid.
Congratulations to the whole Firefox dev team, awesome work!! It is way better than I was expecting in just one version change! :O

Comment: To be fair, the [new UI is already developed for many months](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html). It's just that it was enabled in Firefox 56 by default. If people don't like the new frontend, they can currently still switch back by setting the preference `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend` in `about:config` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

5 years later and I'm having the same issue with Firefox 110.0.1 (64-bit) for macOS, w/ only the `@react-devtools` extension.

**I got it fixed after restarting Firefox twice!**